# I am getting (Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider) Error: E_UNEXPECTED(0x8000FFFF). on oracle provider for OLE DB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ssis, oledb

I have an SSIS package that contains some data flows connected to an oracle database.
I did not have the proper drivers to run the package so i tried to download oracle client alone at first but i faced multiple issues. So i have downloaded the full Oracle 11g environment for win-32.

Now in my ssis package i do have the correct credentials attached to the correct "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" and i am pretty sure that all the credentials are correct. but i am still getting this error when hitting on test connection.

The Error Message that i am getting is the following:

**TITLE: Connection Manager
------------------------------**

**Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. No error message available, result code: E_UNEXPECTED(0x8000FFFF).**

Comment: can you solve the problem?